# Can't access construct variable in method ( php laravel )

Tags: php, laravel

I have a base class which sets up's other extending controllers like this:

```
class BaseController extends Controller
{
    public $globalCurrencies;
    public $globalLanguages;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->globalCurrencies = $this->getCurrencies();  // this works
        $this->globalLanguages = $this->getLanguages(); // this works
    }
}
```

And I use one of helpers to extend this class like this:

```
class SessionHelper extends BaseController
{
    public $test;

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();  // fire parent aka basecontroller construct

        $this->test = $this->globalCurrencies; // this works (variables are set)
        echo '__construct: '.$this->test; // this even displays it
    }

    public function getCurrencies()
    {
        dd('method'.$this->test); // NOT WORKING
    }

    public function getCurrentCurrency()
    {
        return $this->getCurrencies()->where('id', Session::get('currencyId'))->first() ?? null;
    }
}
```

Later on code is used in model:

```
class Product extends Model
{
    protected $table = "products";
    public $timestamps = true;

    public $sessionHelper;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->sessionHelper = new SessionHelper;
    }

    public function getPrice($conversion_rate = null)
    {
        return number_format($this->price_retail / $this->sessionHelper->getCurrentCurrency()->conversion_rate, 2);
    }
}
```

Have any body idea why I can access in construct variable but not in method? If i remember correctly construct is fired first so everything after should have access to it.

Comment: where's `->getCurrentCurrency()` code?

Comment: You should use constructor injection if you want `SessionHelper` class instance in your `Product` class `construct()`, the signature should be `public function __construct(SessionHelper $sessionHelper)` in that case.

Comment: What data type does $this->test return? My guess is that it's an array - you can't die and dump a string with an array. When you say it's not working - what do you mean, you should try and be as specific as possible.

Comment: RyanNghiem code added;   Prafulla  when i inject SessionHelper it throws error: Too few arguments to function App\Models\Product::__construct(), 0 passed in /home/admin/domains/somedomain/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Concerns/HasRelationships.php on line 670 and exactly 1 expected

Comment: @SimonR That could actually be it, although it should return something. If OP does it like this: `dd('method', $this->test);` it should work. I don't see anything else wrong.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake.  $this->test = $this->globalCurrencies;  should be a collection passed from baseController. There is eloquent used to return data from db and pass it to extended controllers. (i did that to avoid multiple calls to the same model due usage in few places). In constructor it shows working collection;  in method  dd displays nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Declare $test variable as private out side the constructor. Inside the constructor keep it the way you are doing it right now and then make a setter and getter for the test variable.

```
    class testObject
 {
 private $test;

 function __construct($test) 
 {
     $this->test= $this->globalCurrencies;
 }

 // test getter
 function getTest() 
 {
     return $this->test;
 }


 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your method to be;

```
public function getCurrencies()
{
    dd('method', $this->test);
}
```

You can not concatenate strings and objects/arrays.

If that doesn't resolve the issue - check the laravel.log